# Clarification of a term used in margin management by top counterparties

Tags: margin, counterparty-risk, initial-margin

I am doing some primary research on margin management for different global counterparties and have come across the paper "[The European central counterparty (CCP) ecosystem](https://www.bis.org/ifc/publ/ifcb46za.pdf)" by Armakolla et al from 2017.

On page 19, the following table is provided to show the the posted the initial margin by some top European clearing members:

[image]

I don't understand the column `IM5/IM`, whose definition as provided is `M5/IM is the portion of initial margin posted by the largest 5 clearing members` in this table.

If I go by this definition, what is exactly meant by 0.73 as `IM5/IM` value for EuroCCP, for example?

Comment: @nbbo2 Thanks. But what is the meaning of `IM5/IM for EuroCCP is 0.73` (5th row in above table)?

Comment: I understand. One more clarification though : Participants means the Clearing members, right?

Comment: yes I agree with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked how to interpret the IM5/IM ratio for EuroCCP.

EuroCCP is now called CBOEClearEurope. The clearing members (participants) are shown here https://clear.cboe.com/europe/services/membership/participants Some of these have bigger initial margin balances than others. If we add up the margins of the 5 biggest (unfortunately they don't tell us the names, but they are on that list, and are probably the more well-known names) it would be 73% of the total balances.

In summary IM5 are the balances of the top 5 and IM is the balances of ALL (approximately 25) participants. IM5/IM is the ratio of these two numbers. It is a measure of risk concentration.